# BigQuery - exclude exclude records with certain values

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to exclude records with certain values. For example, I don't want the BridgeTokens with appName A. Then count the remaining BridgeTokens (Row 2,6,7) grouped by appName.  How to do that in BigQuery? 
The table is:

```
Row   BridgeToken   appName
1     ffffff1       A 
2     ffffff2       B 
3     ffffff3       C
4     ffffff3       B
5     ffffff3       A
6     aaaaaa4       C
7     bbbbbb2       B
```

The result from my query is not accurate.:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(bridgeToken) AS Bridges,
    appName
  FROM
    `<DB>`
  WHERE NOT BridgeToken IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT BridgeToken 
     FROM `<DB>` 
     WHERE appName IN("A")
    AND date < "2018-05-01 00:00:00"
    AND date >= "2018-04-01 00:00:00")
  GROUP BY
    appName 
ORDER BY
  Bridges DESC
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(bridgeToken) AS Bridges,
  appName
FROM  `project.dataset.your_table`
WHERE NOT BridgeToken IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT BridgeToken 
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
  WHERE appName IN("A")
)
GROUP BY appName 
ORDER BY Bridges DESC
```

you can test it with dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT 'ffffff1' BridgeToken, 'A' appName UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ffffff2', 'B' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ffffff3', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ffffff3', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ffffff3', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaaaaa4', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbbbbb2', 'B' 
)
SELECT
  COUNT(bridgeToken) AS Bridges,
  appName
FROM  `project.dataset.your_table`
WHERE NOT BridgeToken IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT BridgeToken 
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` 
  WHERE appName IN("A")
)
GROUP BY appName 
ORDER BY Bridges DESC
```

Result is

```sql
Row Bridges appName  
1   2       B    
2   1       C
```

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail.  This helps greatly.  One extended question, how to include the date range to limit the dataset to the recent month?    For example, date < "2018-05-01 00:00:00"  AND date >= "2018-04-01 00:00:00"

Comment: if you can add dates in your example in question and clarify logic of filtering by dates - I most likely will be able to update my answer then. but meantime, i would assume you can just add respective WHEN statement to outer SELECT (right before GROUP BY)

Comment: I added the date range (e.g. AND lastUsedDate <  "2018-05-01 00:00:00" AND date >= "2018-04-01 00:00:00" after WHERE appName IN("A")), but the return values include all appNames with A/B/C.  The values also should be smaller with the date range, but it's bigger. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I meant - add dates in your example in your questions and explain the logic - so I will be able to update my answer - or someone else will answer